# How to toggle between online and offline mode in hybrid Fiori app?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, sap-fiori, offlineapps

I am creating a hybrid (and web) app using SAP Fiori Kapsel plug-ins, WebIDE and the Mobile Service for Development and Operations from the SAP Cloud.

The web based app is using some of the functionalities that are not supported by the offlline plug-in (e.g. function imports and deep inserts). Both of those features are very important and I have to have them - or something similar - available for the hybrid app aswell.

From my understanding, the hybrid app is launched in "offline mode" by default. I would like to use this offline mode only as a fall back and call the "true" OData service as often as possible.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of creating relationships with the Offline OData plug-in (function imports are not yet supported). In order to explain deep inserts, we would require more information on how exactly you are trying to do it.

It is possible to use both offline/online mode simultaneously. [This blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/24/getting-started-with-kapsel-part-10-offline-odatasp13/) might be helpful. It includes some example of offline - one of which shows a mixed use example (offline/online).

We recommend you to stay in offline mode most of the time and when you need to make an online call, do a flush/upload first, resolve any data conflicts, if any, then make the online call, then do a refresh/download. That will ensure data consistency.